# Can't figure out why my css isn't being changed by my Javascript using Bulma framework

Tags: javascript, css, bulma

I am new to css and Bulma.

This is the relevant code for my problem.

```
for (var i=0; i<20; i++){

  if (i<list.length){

    var textTemplate="{{text}}";
    attach= Mustache.render(textTemplate,list[i]);
    attach=document.createTextNode(attach);
    var basePlate=document.createElement("section");

    basePlate.style.class="section";

    var listPiece=document.createElement("dt");

    listPiece.style.class="container";

    toInsert.appendChild(basePlate);

    basePlate.appendChild(listPiece);

    listPiece.appendChild(attach);
    ....
```

The class changes to basePlate and listPiece isn't changing anything on the actual web page, and I have no idea why. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Because inside object `style` are css properties such `background-color`, `width`, `opacity`, `display`, etc

use:
`listPiece.className="container";`

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className